# Custom Validator not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I realize there are lots of similar posts, however I have not found one that has worked for me unfortunately.  Basically, I have an asp:customvalidator that I am trying to add to a validationgroup with other validators so that all error messages appear in the same alert.  Here is the customvalidator

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtVideo1Url"  Columns="20" Width="98%" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="valURL1" ControlToValidate="txtVideo1Url" OnServerValidate="txtVideo1Url_ServerValidate" Display="None" ValidationGroup="submission" />
```

and here is the event

```
    protected void txtVideo1Url_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
        valURL1.Text = "FAIL!";
    }
```

The event isn't firing at all and I have no idea why.  Once I can get the event firing I can put some actual logic into it, lol

UPDATE: I've noticed that I am now able to get the event firing, however the validationsummary is set to display all errors in a messagebox and this error isn't getting added to the messagebox.

Comment: The answer to your `UPDATE` is that `CustomValidator` is strictly a server-side validation mechanism, while the `MessageBox` capability is a client-side mechanism, thus it is too late to put the `CustomValidator` message into the `MessageBox`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the `CausesValidation` property of the `TextBox` to `true`, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtVideo1Url"  Columns="20" Width="98%" CausesValidation="true" />
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  I just added CausesValidation="true" to the textbox and it's still not triggering

Comment: Like the other answer says (Ilkka) the `ValidationGroup` attribute is the issue, either remove it or add it to the control that does the postback.

Answer (score 28):

Remember to set this property on the CustomValidator...

```
ValidateEmptyText="True"
```

Comment: This worked for me without having to explicitly set the CausesValidation on a textbox.

Comment: Thanks. My event was not firing because control to validate was string empty

Comment: This is the way to do it if your CustomValidator checks the values of several different controls.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add ValidationGroup="submission" to the ASP.NET control that will fire the postback.

Answer (score 1):

CustomValidators don't fire if other Validators in your ASPx are not validating. You may need to force a Page.Validate("something"), with your specific validation group. I suggest look at OnTextChanged event to force a page validate.